# Register custom controller in sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Is this possible to register custom controller in sonata admin? Without any CRUD or other completely unnecessary things,

Simple form with one file uploading (no sonata upload, simple input type file).

Answer (score 0):

Just create usual [controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html) with path in admin zone ("/admin/my_uploader" for example).

You can add menu link using [custom template](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html) for sonata layout.

Another solution is using [ConfigureMenuEvent](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu.html#extending-the-menu), this way can be better if you write reusable bundle.